# How to export project in Android Studio 4.1?

Tags: android-studio, zip, export, project, android-studio-4.1

Today I just have updated my Android studio with version 4.1 but there is no option to export the project to zip in the file menu. Is there any other option to export the project in zipping from Android Studio?

Comment: 'export to zip' option is just removed in Android Studio 4.1 but as a alternative use git or create zip file from project directory manually 
or check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/35697245/1261938

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Android Studio 4.1 the export as ZIP option has been moved to File - > Manage IDE Settings - > Export to Zip file

Answer (score -4):

You can simply create a zip by navigating to your project from your file explorer and sending it to a zip file just as you would any other folder

Comment: Exporting as ZIP gave the project a size of 2B. Zipping the project folder results in a 62MB size.  So having the Android Studio Export as zip option was much better.